# Google Play games unable to send challenge request

Tags: android, google-play-games, challenge-response

I am developing an app in which i have implemented the leader-board and now I want to challenge my friends to beat my best score not to play multiplayer game but i searched a lot for this i didn't get any useful data.
it is very helpful if you suggest me how to achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement a push notification with a message to show your score and with an intent to pointing to your game. You can check out the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for more guidance.

Another way you can adapt, is to integrate it with social media like Facebook and Twitter using posts as a medium for your challenge. Just like how you can see most mobile games.

Comment: but requirement is to post challenge using gmail account only.

Comment: is there any other way except this ?